# App stopped working after calling non-static method from static?

Tags: java, android

When I tried to call non-static method `init()` which is in `Class1` from static which is in `Class2` my app stop working.

Class1.java:

```
public class Class1 extends Activity {
    public void init() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Class2.java:

```
...
Class1 var = new Class1 ();
var.init();
...
```

Compiler doesn't show any errors, but the app still crashes. Does anyone know where could be the problem.

Comment: what is the error you are seeing in logcat?

Comment: Add a try/catch block surrounding your `var.init()` and force a log on logcat. Or just debug the `init()`, line by line.

Comment: There is an error,  You're just not looking hard enough.  Look again and please post the logcat.  You should also take time to understand the difference between compiler errors and runtime errors since you cannot get runtime errors until you have fixed the compiler errors.  No errors in the compiler does not mean no errors in your application. e.g. `int x = 0; int y=5; int z = y /x;` compiles just fine but try running it! I also don't understand your question since Java does not have static classes. You haven't shown anything that is static.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `new` an instance of `Activity` yourself, you have to let the system do it.

You probably want create an `Intent` that *starts* an instance of `Class1`, then you can place your code inside the various lifecycle methods of the `Activity` subclass.

These are all basic Android concepts - read some documentation, grab some sample code and work from there instead of starting from scratch!